# Using checkboxlist to update registry?

Tags: c#, checkbox, foreach, registrykey

I have a check list box that has 5 directories that my program will call later. I want the user to be able to check what directories they want to use with a checklistbox. So far they can chose each item they want and it will be added but i want unchecked boxs to be removed from the registry

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    foreach (object checkbox in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("Item is marked: " + checkbox.ToString() + "\n");
        RegBUP.SetValue(checkbox);
    }
}
```

And so people have a more general idea of what I am doing:
catchpath() returns the path from a directory, so if it gets desktop it returns the path to the desktop.

```
public static void SetValue(object title)
{
    RegistryKey directs = regKey.OpenSubKey("Path to registry", true);
    directs.SetValue(title.ToString(), catchpath(title), RegistryValueKind.String);
    directs.Close();
}
```

Comment: Will all your users have Registry modification access?

Comment: Yes but only access to current user, and to the directories subkey. I store the values in HKCU/software/myprogram/directories values. They will only have the ability to change the 5 keys to enable / disable the actions the program performs.

Comment: You can have all 5 keys in registry and set value as 0 or 1 based on checkbox state if that helps.

Comment: I added more to the question, the value is the path to a directory.

Comment: You can make use of DeleteValue method if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes But I only want to delete the keys that belong to the unchecked box.

Comment: Since there are only 5 values, may I suggest deleting and recreating subkey using DeleteSubKey method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// you can try this

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";

                 for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                        {

                           if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i) == true)
                            {
                           textBox1.AppendText("Item is marked: " +checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString()+ "\n");
                              RegBUP.SetValue(checkedListBox1.Items[i]);
                            }
                           else
                             {
                                 RegBUP.DeleteValue(checkedListBox1.Items[i]);
                             }
                        }
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but reading it it looks like exactly like what I want.